# I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I have a Problem with Updating

Tags: 12.04, updates

```
Fetched 1 B in 34s (0 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ubuntu.qualitynet.net_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
anurag@hanuman:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash sum mismatch error are caused due to missing of some datas while updating the repositories.Try below command before updating repositories,

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run,

```
sudo apt-get update
```